# How to read stream responses generated by pm api sendRequest

Tags: javascript, postman

Trying to run a postman (pm) api call to run a request from the test tab.
Getting back streams in response (logged in console as array containing integers).

Any idea as to how to read these streams.

Request:

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Response:

```
Object:{}
    code:200
    cookie:[]
    header:[]
        0:{}
        1:{}
        2:{}
        3:{}
        4:{}
        5:{}
        6:{}
    id:"e5d5d6d6"
    responseSize:55551
    responseTime:263
    status:"OK"
    stream:{}
        data:[]
            0:123
            1:10
            2:32
            3:32
            4:34
            5:115
            6:119
            7:97
            8:103
            9:103
            10:101
            11:114
            12:34
            13:32
            14:58
            15:32
            16:34
            17:50
            18:46
            19:48
            20:34
            21:44
            22:10
            23:32
            24:32
            25:34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`toJSON()`](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Response.html#toJSON) function on the `Response` object to serialize it to a human-readable format:

```
function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.toJSON())
});
```

See the [`pm` Sandbox API](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) for further reference.

Comment: @BabyGroot yeah, If you just need the response **body**, go for [`json()`](http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Response.html#json) - indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

`res.json()`

This gives the response body in json format.

Usage:

`pm.sendRequest('url', (err, res) => {console.log(res.json());}`

Answer (score 4):

This answer didn't work for me as my reply was a HTML page with embedded JS. I had to use `pm.response.text()` and painstakingly parse out the code I wanted by using `.spit('\n')` to get an array of lines, etc.

Comment: exactly same here. res.toJSON() didn't convert the stream into text. .text() worked for me.

Comment: For my case, this is the correct answer since the data sent from the request is a simple string.

Answer (score 2):

If response of below request is in XML format,

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
}, function (err, res) {
    console.log(res)
});
```

I am trying to convert response using below code

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(res);
```

It is giving error saying

> JSONError | Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

When I used that same function with testscript, It is converting XML to hsonObject

```
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
```

Comment: To get responseBody of xml response need to use below method          var jsonObject = xml2Json(res.text())